# Python escape sequence complex output

Tags: python, string, escaping, sequence

When I am writing the following command in Python IDLE it will give you the output with quotes, I want to know why it is giving such output.

```
x='''''abc\'abcddd'''''

print x
```

This is output of the written code.

```
''abc'abcddd
```

Comment: multi line string has 3 quotes at start & end

Comment: to understand line breaks in python , use of "\". read this : http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: you can upvote my comment if it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to pythons triple quoted strings:

```
''' '''
```

It interprets everything in between as a character. So in your string:

```
'''''abc\'abcddd'''''
```

The first three quotes 'open' the string. Than it encounters 2 quotes, which it interprets as characters. Next it encounters an escaped quote, which would be printed as a quote anyway, but it still uses the escaped quote. It then encounters the first 3 of the last 5 quotes, ending the triple quoted string. It then encounters 2 more quotes forming an empty string `''`.

A space at the places python considers 1 'thing':

```
''' ''abc\'abcddd ''' ''
```

Comment: Good answer, but you should mention that Python automatically concatenates (joins) adjacent string literals.

Comment: But the problem is, double quotes are keep coming at the interval of 6. Meaning that, those double quotes starts at 5 quotes and from that, they keep coming at the interval of 6, like 11 quotes, 17 quotes ,23 quotes and so on. Can you tell me this is happening?